# $X+Y$ or $X-Y$ Normally distributed, but either $X$ or $Y$ (or both) individually non-normal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Curious about whether its true that if $X+Y$ or $X-Y$ are normally distributed, then each individually are normal as well. $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, but in fact correlated.

I know that $X$ and $Y$ normal doesn't necessarily imply that $X+Y$ or $X-Y$ are normal.

I'm wondering about the other direction. I haven't been given whether they are jointly normal or not, only that their sum or difference is.

Any hints?

Comment: isn't it the same question as your second statement since $X = 0.5( X+Y + X-Y)$ ?

Comment: @MarkJoshi  What if we're only given $(X-Y)$ Normal. Can we infer that this means $(X+Y)$ is Normal? i.e. only one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and if $X+Y$ is normally distributed, then  both $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed. This result is due to H. Cramér. The standard proof uses characteristic functions, and relies on a bit of the theory of the growth of entire functions.

Comment: Should have made it more clear, but X & Y are correlated, not independent.  I made the change.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are correlated, you cannot say that $X+Y$ normal implies $X$ and $Y$ normal.

To see this, take $N$ to have standard normal distribution, $X$ independent of $N$ with any distribution, and $Y = N - X$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are correlated, neither of them is normal, and $X + Y = X + N - X = N$.